What is wrong with how I'm adding shapes to my arraylist? Error: "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException"
I am trying to make a painting program where the user can draw shapes, I need to recall them later from and arraylist in another class. Without trying to add the shapes, the program works without error.
This is from the primary GUI class "miniPaint"
if (drawButt.isSelected() == true&& shapesCombo.getValue() == "Line") {
            pane.setOnMousePressed(m->{
                Line line = new Line();
                line.setStroke(currentColor.getFill());
                line.setStartX(m.getSceneX());
                line.setStartY(m.getSceneY());
                pane.getChildren().add(line);
            pane.setOnMouseDragged(q ->{
                    line.setEndX(q.getSceneX());
                    line.setEndY(q.getSceneY());
            pane.setOnMouseReleased(a->{
                    collector.addShape(line);
                    });
                });
            });
        }

collector is the instance of the other class "ShapeCollection", this is the part of it being used
public class ShapeCollection {
    private ArrayList<Line> lines;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles;
    private ArrayList<Ellipse> ellipses;
    
    public ShapeCollection() {
        ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        ArrayList<Ellipse> ellipses = new ArrayList<Ellipse>();
    }
    public void addShape(Shape shape) {
        if (shape instanceof Line) {
            lines.add((Line) shape);
        }
        if (shape instanceof Rectangle) {
            rectangles.add((Rectangle) shape);
        }
        if (shape instanceof Ellipse) {
            ellipses.add((Ellipse) shape);
        }
    }

As soon as I make a line I get this error message (that's the beginning part):
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.add(Object)" because "this.lines" is null
    at Project3/application.ShapeCollection.addShape(ShapeCollection.java:22)
    at Project3/application.MiniPaint.lambda$6(MiniPaint.java:98)

I've tried not doing it through the addShape() method and instead adding directly to the arraylist lines but that worked even less

In the constructor of your ShapeCollection class, you are creating new local variables with the same names as your instance variables, and so your instance variables never get set (default to null). Once that constructor finishes, those local variables will go away.

As an aside, if you're using Java 16+ then you can make use of pattern matching for instanceof. Also, those last two instanceof checks should probably be done with an else if, since if the shape is e.g., a line, then it cannot also be a rectangle or ellipse.

local variables are  hiding global properties . check hints and warnings in your IDE

One way to avoid this issue is to use this when referencing your instance variables.
public class ShapeCollection {
    private ArrayList<Line> lines;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles;
    private ArrayList<Ellipse> ellipses;
    
    public ShapeCollection() {
        this.lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        this.rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        this.ellipses = new ArrayList<Ellipse>();
    }
    public void addShape(Shape shape) {
        if (shape instanceof Line) {
            this.lines.add((Line) shape);
        }
        if (shape instanceof Rectangle) {
            this.rectangles.add((Rectangle) shape);
        }
        if (shape instanceof Ellipse) {
            this.ellipses.add((Ellipse) shape);
        }
    }

Looking at your code, I would recommend against using the above code. I think it's best to make the variables final and go ahead and create them.
public class ShapeCollection {
    final private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
    final private ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    final private ArrayList<Ellipse> ellipses = new ArrayList<Ellipse>();
    
    public ShapeCollection() {
        
    }

    public void addShape(Shape shape) {
        if (shape instanceof Line) {
            lines.add((Line) shape);
        }
        if (shape instanceof Rectangle) {
            rectangles.add((Rectangle) shape);
        }
        if (shape instanceof Ellipse) {
            ellipses.add((Ellipse) shape);
        }
    }

